# How to create a draggable marker?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-gmap

Code below it's able to create a marker.

But I want to create a draggable marker, problem is that is not sending the click event to the server after the marker has been created.

When the markes is created the *draggable* flag is set to true.

Any ideas?

```html
<p:gmap id="gmap" center="36.890257,30.707417" zoom="13" type="HYBRID"

style="width:600px;height:400px"
model="#{mapBean.emptyModel}"
onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);"
widgetVar="map">
<p:ajax event="markerDrag" listener="#{mapBean.onMarkerDrag}" update="messages" />
</p:gmap>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" effect="FADE" effectDuration="0.5" close="false" fixedCenter="true">
<h:form prependId="false">
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
<h:outputLabel value="Are you sure?"/>


<f:facet name="footer">
<p:commandButton value="Yes"
actionListener="#{mapBean.addMarker}"
update=":messages"
oncomplete="markerAddComplete()"/>
<p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="return cancel()"/>
</f:facet>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:inputHidden id="lat" value="#{mapBean.lat}"/>
<h:inputHidden id="lng" value="#{mapBean.lng}"/>
</h:form>
</p:dialog>

<script type="text/javascript">
var currentMarker = null;

function handlePointClick(event) {

console.log("click event");

console.log(event.marker);

if (currentMarker == null) {
document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();

currentMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng())
});

map.addOverlay(currentMarker);

dlg.show();
}
}

function markerAddComplete() {
//currentMarker = null; Only one can be added.
dlg.hide();
}

function cancel() {
dlg.hide();
currentMarker.setMap(null);
currentMarker = null;

return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was being caused with the attribute *onPointClick* of *p:gmap*. This is a Javascript Callback to the function *handlePointClickEvent()* in this case.

So I setted this attribute with an *EL* expression, so after creating the marker, this expression would evaluate to *null*, component *p:gmap* updates in an AJAX call, and draggable events work now ;)

Comment: Hi, I've been experiencing same problem, could you please elaborate on your solution ? I don't really understand what you mean by "setting this attribute with an EL expression". TY!