# Create draggable markers

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jboss7.x

I have seen in PrimeFaces demo an example on Adding markers and on Draggable markers. However I need to integrate both these things into one working examples and was not sucessful so far.

Here is what I have so far (relevant part of the codes)

addevent.xhtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentMarker = null;

    function handlePointClick(event) {
        if(currentMarker == null) {
            document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();

            dlg.show();

            console.log("HandlePoint Click do we have anything?"+event.latLng.lat());
        }

        return true;
    }

    function markerAddComplete() {

        currentMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('lat').value,  document.getElementById('lng').value)
        });



        var title = document.getElementById('title');
        var type = document.getElementById('location');
        var typeOut;

        console.log("type:"+type);
        console.log("type value:"+type.value);
        console.log("type value to string"+type.value.toString());

        if (type.value.toString() == "START") {
            typeOut = "Start";
            currentMarker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png");
        }
        else if (type.value.toString() == "END") {
            typeOut = "End";
            currentMarker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png");
        }
        else {
            typeOut = "Checkpoint";

            currentMarker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png");
        }

        currentMarker.setTitle("Description: "+title.value+"\nType: "+typeOut);
        title.value = "";
        type.value = "";
        typeOut = "";
        map.addOverlay(currentMarker);
        // currentMarker.setDraggable(true);

        currentMarker = null;
        dlg.hide();


    }

    function cancel() {
        dlg.hide();
        currentMarker.setMap(null);
        currentMarker = null;

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

...

```
                <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{mapBean.onMarkerSelect}" />
                <p:gmapInfoWindow>
                    <p:outputPanel style="text-align:center;display:block;margin:auto:">

                        <h:outputText value="Title: #{mapBean.currentMarker.title}"/><br/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{mapBean.deleteCurrentMarker}" partialSubmit="true" process="gmap" update="gmap" />
                    </p:outputPanel>

                </p:gmapInfoWindow>
                <!-- ignore -->
                <ui:remove>
                    <p:ajax event="markerDrag" listener="#{mapBean.onMarkerDrag}" />
                </ui:remove>
            </p:gmap>
```

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" effect="FADE" showEffect="explode" effectDuration="0.5" close="false">
    <h:form prependId="false">


        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title" />
            <p:inputText id="title" value="#{mapBean.title}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Location type" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="location" value="#{mapBean.location}" required="true">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{mapBean.locations}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{mapBean.addMarker}"
                                 oncomplete="markerAddComplete()"/>
                <p:button value="Cancel" onclick="return cancel()"/>
            </f:facet>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:inputHidden id="lat" value="#{mapBean.lat}" />
        <h:inputHidden id="lng" value="#{mapBean.lng}" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Backing Bean MapBean.java

```
public void addMarker(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  

    logger.info("MapBean add marker event ?");

    LatLng coord = new LatLng(lat,lng); 

    String iconUrl;

    if (this.location == LocationType.START) {
        logger.info("green icon");
        iconUrl = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png";
    }
    else if (this.location == LocationType.END) {
        logger.info("red icon");
        iconUrl = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png";
    } 
    else {
        logger.info("yellow icon");
        iconUrl = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png";
    }

    Marker marker = new Marker(coord, "Description: "+this.getTitle()+"\n Type:"+this.location.toString(),this.location,iconUrl);
//  marker.setDraggable(true); // this was of course un-commented previously

    //logger.info("is draggable:"+marker.isDraggable());


    mapModel.addOverlay(marker);
  //marker.setDraggable(true); 

    addMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Marker Added", "Lat:" + lat + ", Lng:" + lng));  
}  

 public void onMarkerDrag(MarkerDragEvent event) {  

        logger.info("DRAGGING !!!");

        Marker marker = event.getMarker();  

        logger.info("Lat:" + marker.getLatlng().getLat() + ", Lng:" + marker.getLatlng().getLng());
    }
```

So the issue is that I can make my markers draggable - but only at the client side, the onMarkerDrag method is never called.

We have observed when this attribute is set
 onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);"
this listener does not work

If I remove onPointClick it works.

But for now I have to choose - I want to either have my markers draggable or I want to have a possibility to add them. I would obviously want to have both things..

Any ideas what might be the issue ?

I have found this topic on stackoverflow, couldnt really figured the solution out.
[How to create a draggable marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736705/how-to-create-a-draggable-marker)

I am using JBoss AS 7.1.1
PrimeFaces 3.5
JSF 2.1 (provided by JBoss)

Cheers,
OSiRiS

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't tell you exactly what you are doing wrong because I can't make sense of the code you posted (incomplete and badly formatted...sorry). However, after getting familiar with the examples online ***I think***  I can tell you why your markers were not being dragged after you added one to the map. I'm also going to provide you my working sample since you've been waiting so long for an answer.

When you called `map.addOverLay` via the javascript, you were indeed setting a marker on the client side and (assuming that your code worked) updating the server side after clicking Add. However, you needed to **reload** `p:gmap` with the updated collection of markers that were on the server. When you added the new marker, `p:gmap` was still referencing the old collection. Therefore, when you tried to move it you couldn't. As far as `p:gmap` was concerned no `MarkerDragEvent` was being fired because you were not dragging one of ***its*** markers. You were simply touching a static image that was set by `map.addOverlay`. So to fix this, you need to update `p:gmap` after clicking Add by adding it in the `p:ajax` list

```
<p:commandButton id="test" value="Add"   
                                     actionListener="#{mapBean.addMarker}"   
                                     update=":growl, :gmap"   
                                     oncomplete="markerAddComplete()"/>
```

That's really it honestly. As far as the answer from the similar problem you found...I can't make sense of it either. Anyway, here is the the code

**Index.xhtml**

```
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <h:outputScript name="javascript/common.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>  

    <p:gmap id="gmap" center="36.890257,30.707417" zoom="13" type="HYBRID" 
            style="width:600px;height:400px" model="#{mapBean.draggableModel}" 
            onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);" widgetVar="map">
        <p:ajax event="markerDrag" listener="#{mapBean.onMarkerDrag}" update="growl" />  
    </p:gmap>  

    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade">  
        <h:form prependId="false">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title:" />  
                <p:inputText id="title" value="#{mapBean.title}" />  

                <f:facet name="footer">  
                    <p:commandButton id="test" value="Add"   
                                     actionListener="#{mapBean.addMarker}"   
                                     update=":growl, :gmap"   
                                     oncomplete="markerAddComplete()"/>  
                    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="return cancel()"/>  
                </f:facet>  
            </h:panelGrid>  

            <h:inputHidden id="lat" value="#{mapBean.lat}" />  
            <h:inputHidden id="lng" value="#{mapBean.lng}" />  
        </h:form>  
    </p:dialog>  
</h:body>
```

**MapBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
public class MapBean implements Serializable {  

    private MapModel draggableModel;  
    private String title;  
    private double lat;  
    private double lng;  

    public MapBean() {  
        draggableModel = new DefaultMapModel();  

        //Shared coordinates  
        LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(36.879466, 30.667648);  
        LatLng coord2 = new LatLng(36.883707, 30.689216);  
        LatLng coord3 = new LatLng(36.879703, 30.706707);  
        LatLng coord4 = new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323);  

        //Draggable  
        draggableModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Konyaalti","Konyaalti","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png"));  
        draggableModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord2, "Ataturk Parki", "Ataturk Parki","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png"));  
        draggableModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord3, "Karaalioglu Parki", "Karaalioglu Parki","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png"));  
        draggableModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord4, "Kaleici", "Kaleici", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png"));  

        for(Marker marker : draggableModel.getMarkers()) {  
            marker.setDraggable(true);  
        }  
    }  

    public MapModel getDraggableModel() {  
        return draggableModel;  
    }  

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public void onMarkerDrag(MarkerDragEvent event) {  
        Marker marker = event.getMarker();  
        addMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Marker Dragged", "Lat:" + marker.getLatlng().getLat() + ", Lng:" + marker.getLatlng().getLng()));  
    }  

    public void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
    }  

    public void addMarker(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
        Marker marker = new Marker(new LatLng(lat, lng), title, "SOME VALUE", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png");  
        marker.setDraggable(true);  
        draggableModel.addOverlay(marker);  

        addMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Marker Added", "Lat:" + lat + ", Lng:" + lng + "Is marker draggable ?" + marker.isDraggable()));  
    }  
}
```

**common.js**

This file contains the javascript. I was using Netbeans and this file was located in a folder called javascript in the following directory Web Pages/resources/javascript. No need to mix it with the JSF. Try to be clean, it will help you in the long run. The code is basically [the same as the example online](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/gmapAddMarkers.jsf) so you can just copy it from there. The only thing I did was take out the `<script>` tags and moved it all in that file. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to add draggable markers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Remove an overlay</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
        var map;
        var markers = [];
        var marker, infowindow;
        function initialize() {
            var haightAshbury = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -122.4469157);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: haightAshbury,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                    mapOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                addMarker(event.latLng);
            });
        }

        // Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
        function addMarker(location) {
            var temp
            if (marker!=null) {
                temp=marker
                marker=null;
            }
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', markerListener);

            function markerListener() {
                alert(this.getPosition());
                // this.setIcon(...
            }
            markers.push(marker);
        }

        // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
        function setAllMap(map) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                markers[i].setMap(map);
            }
        }

        // Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array.
        function clearOverlays() {
            setAllMap(null);
        }

        // Shows any overlays currently in the array.
        function showOverlays() {
            setAllMap(map);
        }

        // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
        function deleteOverlays() {
            clearOverlays();
            markers = [];
        }


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="panel">
    <input onclick="clearOverlays();" type=button value="Hide Overlays">
    <input onclick="showOverlays();" type=button value="Show All Overlays">
    <input onclick="deleteOverlays();" type=button value="Delete Overlays">
</div>


<div id="map"></div>
<p>Click on the map to add markers.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The css/style.css file:

```
html, body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
}
#map {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 750px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

It is extremely tough for me to judge the problem by going through your code.But you can take the above code as model and form your code accordingly. Pls note that it uses google maps api version 3.